# Phone authentication google firebase failed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I used google firebase phone authentication this is my code: https://codeshare.io/5MrgVy
until yesterday it worked, today instead every time I enter a phone number the toast appears which should appear in this case:

```
public void onVerificationFailed (FirebaseException e) {loadingBar.dismiss ();

                Toast.makeText (RegistrationActivity.this, "Invalid number entered ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show ();
                relativeLayout.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);


                continueAndNextBtn.setText ("Continue"); // Continue
                codeText.setVisibility (View.GONE);


            }
```

Lately I did a referactor to change the name of the project package, and after doing this it gave me this error: No matching client found for package name 'com.conta.ftof'
I solved that error by replacing the old packages inside google-services.json with the new one. I told you this because I'm afraid this is the cause. How could I fix the authentication fact?

edit:

I noticed this strange thing in the build output:

activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android: launchMode was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml: 24 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present

logcat

```
2020-10-11 21:25:28.819 15302-15302/com.conta.ftof E/RegistrationActivity: err : com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed ]
```

AndroidMAnifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.conta.ftof">



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".donate" />
        <activity android:name=".VideoCallActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CallingActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".FindPeopleActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".NotificationsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ContactsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" />
        <activity android:name=".RegistrationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />



                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3400243939195187~6852949310"/>

        <receiver android:name=".ReminderBroadcast"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `om.conta.ftof E/RegistrationActivity: err : com.google.firebase.FirebaseNetworkException: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred` look it is one of the errors i mentioned in the answer. there is network problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there can be many reasons of the failure. you can try the folowing

- if you had been testing on emulator. it wont work
- if you had beeen testing using the same phone number again and again then firebase ll block your number for 24 hrs and sometimes even more just to stop the abuse. for overcoming the quote exceed error you can create test mobile numbers in fireabse console => https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#test-with-fictional-phone-numbers
- internet connection
- some android certificate error

try checking every case

[EDIT]: FIREBASE PHONE AUTH ERROR HANDLING

try the following code it ll help you a bit

```
@Override
public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
    if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
        // Failed to verify due to wrong format mobile number
    } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
        // Failed to verify due to usage over quota limit
    }
}
```

Comment: @PietroContadini check every case and say what you get

Comment: • i don't use an emulator, i use my real phone                                                                     
• I don't think this is the reason why I tried to change the phone number and the toast keeps appearing •If you intend not to be connected to a wi-fi network but to be connected to the data connections when testing the app, this too I tried but it still doesn't work •i didn't understand this point here. What is android certificate error?

Comment: @PietroContadini you need to add the sha256 of the android app to your firebase console and will you please log the adjact error

Comment: in the methof `onVerificationFailed (FirebaseException e)` log the value of `e` like `Log.e(TAG,  "err : " + e)` and post the error it ll help a lot

Comment: how do i add it? I would like to point out that this morning I generated a signed version of the app (if it helps)

Comment: @PietroContadini ok try logging the error and comment back

Comment: this is the code of how I made the log:

private static final String TAG = "RegistrationActivity";

public void onVerificationFailed (FirebaseException e) {

                Log.e (TAG, "err:" + e);
                loadingBar.dismiss ();

                Toast.makeText (RegistrationActivity.this, "Invalid number entered ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show ();
                relativeLayout.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);


                continueAndNextBtn.setText ("Continue"); // Continue
                codeText.setVisibility (View.GONE);


            }

Comment: @PietroContadini will you post the error please what do you get in the logcat ?

Comment: @PietroContadini add it to your question. copy the value of `e` logged in logcat and edit you question and add it there

Comment: @PietroContadini if you dont see an edit button at the end of your question and post an answer with the logcat value

Comment: I don't know if the ones I pasted are the logcats. if they weren't, I can't find the logcat window

Comment: in android studio go to `View/Tools WIndow/Logcat` or press `Alt + 6` and a window ll open in that window search for the error

Answer (score 0):

@Harkal

Logcat after the click on the btn continue

```
2020-10-11 21:25:28.819 15302-15302/com.conta.ftof E/RegistrationActivity: err : com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed ]
```

Comment: there is network error. either you have not included the internet permission or you have low network or no network at all. please mark my answer as correct if it helped

Comment: @Harkal How i can include the authorization?

Comment: have you added internet permision to manifest file ?  if so then check your device have internet connection

Comment: @Harkal Yes: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.conta.ftof">



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: @Harkal my device has the connection, I also tried from two different devices but it still doesn't work ..
this is very strange

Comment: I added permissions and now the logcats have changed, I put the update on my initial message

Comment: @Harkal I believe the cause of this is that changing the package name changed the SHA -1 KEY

Answer (score 0):

I solved. The cause was that I had changed the package name and therefore would have to change the package name in firebase as well. I created a new app on firebase and this time I put the right package name, replacing the google-services.json file with the old one ... Now it works!