# Verification failed(Firebase android)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make an app for phone number authentication through firebase. But I keep getting the message verification failed.
Here is the code for OTP authentication:-

```
    private void sendVerificationCode(){
        String phoneN =phone.getText().toString();
        
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneN,                           60,                 
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   
                Registration.this,               
                mCallbacks);        

    }

    PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks= new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this,"verification completed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this,"verification failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            //super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            codeSent=s;
        }
    };
    private void VerifyCode(){
        String code= otp.getText().toString();
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(codeSent, code);
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }
    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Welcome, You can login now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Registration.this,Login_Reg.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        } else {
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                // The verification code entered was invalid
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Incorrect Verification Code",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

I keep getting the message "verification failed".
Below is the UI.

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64305866/phone-authentication-google-firebase-failed/64307304#64307304

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution...Try to run it on an actual device. It will work.